# Merge close similar linestrings in Shapely/python

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

### Problem

I projected 3D faces to 2D lines/splines. In most of the cases my approach works, however I have an issue in one case. The spline sub-strings are looking like they are completely on top of each other. However, zooming in reveals that there are tiny distances, leading to a distorted result.
I would like to merge them to a single linestring.

### What I tried so far

I am working completely with shapely and standard python libraries.
I am using unary_union and linemerge to clean my set of lines. I tried using shapely.ops snap but it doesnt solve the problem either.
One idea has been to buffer the line strings and unite the polygons and "de"buffer afterwards. However, I did not manage to get this to work yet.

### Exemplary images

[image: Starting point]
[image: Zooming]
[image: Union]

### Question

Is there a possibility to merge those really really close linestring segments?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by merging them? If you want them all to have exactly the same path, why don't you choose one of the candidates as the new geometry for all the other almost overlapping features? Or do you want to get some kind of "average path" of these lines ?